# Difficult augmented matrices question.

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm currently revising for a maths module that I am taking as part of my physics degree.

The final part of the matrices section of a paper I was doing included this question:

Solve the this set of simultaneous equations:
$$
x + log_2y +z(z+1) = 0 \\ 3x + log_2y^2 + \frac{3}{2}z(z+1) = 0 \\2x + log_2\frac{1}{y}- \frac{1}{2}z(z+1) = 4
$$

---

I can solve simple systems of linear simultaneous equations by using matrices however this threw me. I tried this matrix: $$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2^y & z+1 & 0 \\
3 & 2^{y^2} & \frac{3}{2}(z+1) & 0 \\
2 & 2^\frac{1}{y} & -\frac{1}{2}(z+1) & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
 $$
However I am pretty sure that not only is this attempt wrong but also that I have no idea how to solve this.

Thanks! Sean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the substitution $\tilde{y}=\log_2 y$ and $\tilde{z}=z(z+1)$ leads to the equivalent *linear* system
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x &+& &\tilde{y} &+& &\tilde{z} &= 0,\\
3x &+& 2&\tilde{y} &+& \frac{3}{2}&\tilde{z} &= 0,\\
2x&-&&\tilde{y}&-&\frac{1}{2}&\tilde{z} &= 4
\end{eqnarray}
$$
solved by $x=1$, $\tilde{y}=-3$, $\tilde{z}=2$. Hence $y=2^{\tilde{y}}=2^{-3}=1/8$ and $z$ is obtained by solving $z(z+1)=2$, that is, $z=1$ or $z=-2$.

Comment: Oh I never though doing that, it's so much simpler now. Thanks a bunch!